# Command to fill paragraph with repeated text (alignment/spacing problem)

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, boxes

I am trying to define a command `\todopar[dummy]{msg}` that fills a paragraph with `dummy` repeated a number of times and `msg` typeset centered in the paragraph.

The end result should look like this (without the spacing issues)

[image: desiderata]

My first attempt is

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{todocol}{green!30!black}

\newcommand{\repetita}[1]{\leavevmode\xleaders\hbox{#1\ }\hfill\kern0pt}
\newcommand{\todopar}[2][To Do]{%
  \par\medskip\noindent{%
  \color{todocol!50!white}
  \null\repetita{#1}\\%
  \null\repetita{#1}\\%
  \null\repetita{#1}%
  \textcolor{todocol}{#2}%
  \repetita{#1}\\%
  \null\repetita{#1}\\%
  \null\repetita{#1}\par\medskip%
}}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum*[1]
  \todopar{This is somehing we have to do soooo bad that takes even more than one line oh my gosh.}
  \lipsum*[1]
  \todopar{Lot of work}
  \lipsum*[1]
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, using `\xleaders` I do not get the dummy text in the central line aligned with the ones in the rest of the paragraph, plus the contents of the `hbox` of the leaders end with a space which means that the last repetition will end the line with a space as well.

How can I solve these two problems?
Is there a more elegant way to implement this effect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use a paragraph rather than leaders:

[image]

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{todocol}{green!30!black}


\newcommand{\todopar}[2][To Do]{%
% end the previous par and start a local group
  \par\medskip{%
% special para uses full length lines, no white space
% at start or end
  \parindent0pt
  \parfillskip0pt
% set colour for the filler text
  \color{todocol!50!white}%
% save filler text in box, for measuring
  \sbox0{#1 }%
% 
% Set the message text in a normal paragraph with normal
% \parfillskip to allow the last line to be short as usual.
% the whole construct is inside a scratch box 2.
  \setbox2\vbox{\parfillskip\fill\strut#2\unskip\strut
% Finish the paragraph with the message text
  \par
% Probably not needed but remove any glue or penalty
% after the last line
  \unskip\unpenalty
% remove the last (or only) line of the message paragraph
  \setbox0\lastbox
% 
% At this point box0 is always full width but contains the last
% line of the message followed by \rightskip and \parfillskip glue
% so \unskip twice and globally save box1 with the natural length
% of the last line of the message.
  \global\setbox1\hbox{\unhbox0\unskip\unskip}%
% 
% Now remove the baselineskip glue before that last line.
  \unskip\unpenalty\unskip\unpenalty
% and finish the box
  }%
% Now box2 contains all the lines of the message except the last
% so for a short message it will be empty
% 
% see how many filler text it takes for 2 lines of text
  \count0=\dimexpr2\columnwidth\relax
  \divide\count0 \wd0 %
% 
% see how many filler text it takes to pad one side
% of a line that has the (last line of) the message in
% the middle
  \count2=\dimexpr(\columnwidth-\wd1-2em)/2\relax
  \divide\count2 \wd0 %
% 
% save the filler text, use a macro rather than the box
% to allow any white space in the filler to stretch
  \def\tmp{\strut#1 }%
% 
% make a paragraph of \count0 copies of the filler making
% a two full length  line paragraph
  \xrep{\count0}\par
% 
% unbox box 2 this is the initial full length lines of the message
% in the main color. As this is unboxed it is a normal sequence of
% line boxes and glue so can break at a page. 
  {\color{todocol}\unvbox2}%
% 
% Now make a 1-line paragraph with count2 copies of filler
% either side of the last line of the message, with a word space 
% padding either side/
  \xrep{\count2} \textcolor{todocol}{\unhbox1} \xrep{\count2}\par
% 
% As before a 2 line filler paragraph
  \xrep{\count0}\par%
% 
% end the local group
  }%
% A skip to match the one at the start.
 \medskip}

% A simple recursive loop macro, makes #1
% copies of \tmp
\def\xrep#1{%
\ifnum#1>0 
\tmp
\xrep{\numexpr#1-1\relax}%
\fi}

% A test document....
\begin{document}
  \lipsum*[1]
  \todopar{This is somehing we have to do soooo bad that takes even more than one line oh my gosh.}
  \lipsum*[1]
  \todopar{Lot of work}
  \lipsum*[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, this gives a great result although I still have to understand every line. I would put `\par\medskip` before changing `\parindent` and `\parfillskip` so the previous paragraph is unaltered even if no space occurs between it and `\todopar`

Comment: I would also use `\linewidth` instead of `\textwidth` to support two column layouts

Comment: @Bordaigorl Use `\columnwidth` that is good in both cases.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle could you briefly explain how you construct the boxes? I kind of get the calculations on the widths and `\xrep` but I am not sure how you manage to construct the centered paragraph so that it can break in multiple lines and even across pages

Comment: @Bordaigorl I'll add some comments to the code....

Comment: @Bordaigorl try now

Comment: @DavidCarlisle brilliant thanks! It's much clearer now!

Comment: @Bordaigorl probably it should use \@tempcnta and \@tempcntb rather than \count0 and \count2 or it will mess up the page counter if a page break happens within the local group.